# How to use Map inside Select

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Input:

```
Select[Range[10], 2 <= # <= 5 || 8 <= # <= 10 &]
```

Output:

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}
```

In case I have lots of conditions I want to have them defined separately like this:

Input:

```
cond = {{2, 5}, {8, 10}};
Or @@ (#[[1]] <= q <= #[[2]] & /@ cond)
```

Output:

```
2 <= q <= 5 || 8 <= q <= 10
```

How to combine my first input with my second input to have all the code in my formula?

Comment: Just use `Between[]`: `Select[Range[50], Between[{{2, 5}, {11, 19}, {26, 33}, {44, 49}}]]`

Comment: OK. But I would like to know also how to do it with Map. In case I wanted a more complex conditions not just simple inequalities.

Comment: Would something like `With[{sel = ReleaseHold[Hold[Function][Apply[Or, # <= Hold[Slot][1] <= #2 & @@@ {{2, 5}, {11, 19}, {26, 33}, {44, 49}}]]]}, Select[Range[50], sel]]` suit your needs?

Comment: Define a helper function

`cond = {{2, 5}, {8, 10}};
test[x_] = Or @@ (#[[1]] <= x <= #[[2]] & /@ cond);

Select[Range[10], test]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) with a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition):

```
Cases[Range[10], q_ /; 2<=q<=5||8<=q<=10]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}

or [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select) with a pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function):

```
Select[Range[10], Function[q, 2<=q<=5||8<=q<=10]]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}